# Etymology of "fixing someone's wagon"

Tags: etymology, expressions

I'm looking for the origin of the expression: "fixing someone's wagon".

As in:

> Alice, with malice on her face, exclaimed "Maybe some hijinks will
>   teach that scoundrel!"
>
> Bob rolled his eyes and sarcastically responds, "Yea,
>   that'll really **fix his wagon!**"

I've found [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=fix+someone%27s+wagon) and [here](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fix_someone%27s_wagon) that it's basically about bringing someone their downfall, but why?

I love the phrase, but I can't figure out how "fixing someone's wagon" equated to ruining their chances of success, or bringing about their downfall, etc.? Were wagon mechanics particularly malicious?

Comment: You want etymology, unless you're sure the phrase is a bug.

Comment: *Fix* can mean something like *sabotage*, with the right context. It's a versatile word, spanning not only the extremes of typical auto-antonyms but also the middle portion as well.

Comment: [Link to back up @Lawrence](http://wordsgoingwild.blogspot.co.uk/2012/04/getting-even.html)

Comment: https://www.answers.com/Q/Where_does_the_phrase_fix_his_wagon_come_from

Comment: @GEdgar it's not really clear what you're answering - that link seems to just be a "gee, I dunno" response?

Comment: See what the dictionary says about some of the seemingly opposite meanings of *fix*, which evolved perhaps by ironic use.

Comment: My mother (b.1936) always said: *"I'll fix your ***little red*** wagon!"* - in the sense of *'taking someone down a peg'* or, humbling them in their arrogance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be an extended metaphor surrounding the phrase that I don't quite get. The very earliest references refer to badly behaving women, with various other references to transportation alongside the wagon bit.

Here's an early and surprising example from the 1945 Congressional Record, Vol 91, part 7, p8893  That appears to talk about spiking an election.
[image]

Now we're gettin somewhere - *I'm gonna fix your wagon*, copywrite 1937.

[image]

Gil Rodgers' version of the song: https://youtu.be/uYfC9yya1i0

1934 - *All the Skeletons in All the Closets*, by Keith Fowler, p211.

[image]

Comment: This is the first time I have seen the word 'commuting' used pejoratively. There might well be another question lurking here.